# Why do I get NaN on basic arithmetic for two variables taken from document.getElement?

Tags: javascript, addition

Why do I get `NaN` on variable `result1`?. I tried adding `parseInt` but without success. Can someone shed light on what the issue is?

```js
let x = +document.getElementsByClassName("number1")[0];
let y = +document.getElementsByClassName("number2")[0];
let result1 = x + y;
document.getElementById("ok1").innerHTML = result1;

document.getElementById("numberOrnot").innerHTML = typeof result1;
```

```html
<div class="number1">33</div>
<div class="number2">11</div>
<div id="ok1"></div>

<div id="numberOrnot"></div>
```

Comment: Because `x` and `y` contain Element objects, not the content of the elements.

Comment: You’re missing `.textContent`.

Comment: Thanks @Rory McCrossan and Sebastian Simon Solution is +document.getElementsByClassName("number1")[0].textContent;